# Managed debugging not available (version of mscordbi.dll not found)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

Within the last few days, visual studio (2017, Professional) has lost the ability to debug memory dumps in managed or mixed mode. The error given is: "Managed debugging is not available for this minidump. A required library for managed minidump debugging, 'mscordbi.dll', version '4.0.30319.0', could not be located....."

This is the same message seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138092/managed-debugging-does-not-work-anymore-due-to-wrong-version-of-mscordbi-dll)

This is a secure internet-limited environment, so the usual methods of symbol servers do not apply.

I regularly use symchk to create a manifest file, which I can gather symbols for memory dumps in question. This file (mscordbi.dll) is never included in those manifests. I suspect possibly a recent (2019 OCT) Windows update as what broke this, but there is no ability to rollback in this secure environment.

I have checked which versions of this DLL are on my system (Windows 10 system, using .NET 4.7). I have a few versions, and managed obtain a copy of 4.0.30319.1, which I added to the directories, but still no success.

I have purged/emptied and rebuilt by symbolcache, to no avail.

I uninstalled and reinstalled VS2017 Pro, issue persists.

I tried to find this particular DLL version on some of those DLL download websites, but have had no luck either

Edit: To be clear, I could debug specific memory and crash dumps in Mixed Mode before, and now I no longer can.

Comment: 1.I wonder if you are using the latest managed debugging engine and it seems that it is no longer compatible with c++ since VS2012. You can try debugging your code using managed compatibility mode(the old version).

2.Besides, one possibility is that mscordbi.dll is not recognized by VS. You can try to register this DLL in the GAC.(Run CMD as administrator then type"regsvr32 mscordbi.dll").