# Managed debugging does not work anymore, due to wrong version of mscordbi.dll. Again

Tags: vb.net, debugging, dump, debug-symbols, mscorlib

When I try to open a dump from a VB.Net application, I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Managed debugging is not available for this minidump.

A required library for managed minidump debugging, 'mscordbi.dll', version '4.0.30319.0', could not be located.

Restart your debug session after trying one or more of the following steps: 
 1. If this computer is not currently connected to the internet, connect so the dll can be downloaded from Microsoft.
 2. Specify the path to 'mscordbi.dll' in Symbol Settings under Debugger options.
 3. Select 'Debug with Native Only'.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

First I thought of listening to the error message, so I checked for all "mscordbi.dll" files in my computer. They seem to be located in C:\Windows\WinSxS, so I launched the following command in the command prompt (in order to know the versions):

```
SigCheck -s mscordbi*.dll | findstr "Windows Prod version"
```

This gives answers like:

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_netfx-mscordbi_dll_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.19041.1_none_e961a7e0d8f1c351\mscordbi.dll:
        Product:        Microsoft« .NET Framework
        Prod version:   2.0.50727.9149
        File version:   2.0.50727.9149 (WinRelRS6.050727-9100)
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_netfx4-mscordbi_dll_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15805.0_none_087dbced068592d9\mscordbi.dll:
        Prod version:   4.8.4084.0
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_netfx4-mscordbi_dll_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15805.110_none_00498860c18c147d\mscordbi.dll:
        Prod version:   4.8.4180.0
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_netfx4-mscordbi_dll_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15805.470_none_00498d3ac18c0dd8\mscordbi.dll:
        Prod version:   4.8.4515.0
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_netfx-mscordbi_dll_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.19041.1_none_310edeb7ed6dec57\mscordbi.dll:
        Prod version:   2.0.50727.9149
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_netfx4-mscordbi_dll_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15805.0_none_502af3c41b01bbdf\mscordbi.dll:
        Prod version:   4.8.4084.0
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_netfx4-mscordbi_dll_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15805.110_none_47f6bf37d6083d83\mscordbi.dll:
        Prod version:   4.8.4180.0
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_netfx4-mscordbi_dll_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15805.470_none_47f6c411d60836de\mscordbi.dll:
        Prod version:   4.8.4515.0
```

(those results are not accurate: apparently the command always yields "Product", "Prod Version" and "File version", although I would like only to see "Prof version", but I don't know how to filter this from `FindStr` results.)

As you can see from the results, the requested version is not present, but so what?
So, I remember [having asked this same question already before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138092). There I have found for myself that I need to empty the symbol cache, but here, even after having emptied the symbol cache, the problem still persists (so this is surely **not** a duplicate of my own question :-) ).

I need to add that the mentioned older question was asked when I was programming in C++, while now I'm programming in C# (and the current dump is in VB.Net).